# how to get label of selectbox in PHP by its value - Typo3

Tags: php, label, typo3

Theres a selectbox in Typo3 backend of one of my plugins. The option values are 0,1,2,3... The option-name or label itself contains the Text: foo,bar,whatever,...

Now whats saved in the DB is the value. But i need to show the label or name.
The extension, plugin is set up with Kickstarter or its also ok for me to change something myself in files if needed.

I know its possible to change the value from 0-x to its label. But i dont like it and i will just do it if theres no way to get the label, name.

Someone knows how to get them based on the value of the option or its even possible?

heres my php - $v['category'] is 0,1,2,3... from the selectbox:

```
    $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
        '*', 
        'sometable',
        '',
        '',
        'title ASC',
        ''
    );
    while($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $projects[] = $row;
    }

    $content = '<div class="projectlist">';
    foreach ($projects as $k => $v) {
        $content.= '<div class="project-single">';
        $content.= $v['title'].' | '.$v['category'];
        $content.= '</div>';
    }
    $content.= '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$v['category']` contains the id, you can look up the value in your `locallang.xml`:

```
foreach ($projects as $k => $v) {
        $content.= '<div class="project-single">';
        $content.= $v['title'].' | '.$this->pi_getLL('category_'.$v['category']);
        $content.= '</div>';
    }
```

Presuming your `locallang.xml` has the entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
    <data type="array">
        <languageKey index="default" type="array">
            <label index="category_1">Category label 1</label>
            <label index="category_2">Category label 2</label>
        </languageKey>
    </data>
</T3locallang>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your good approach but... **1)** It's not certain that the labels actually are in a language file. Yes, they should be but the programmer might have taken a dirty way and have the labels directly in the TCA configuration, giving up on the multilingual backend. **2)** The frontend plugin IMHO loads different XML file than the one used for the backend labels so either the labels will have to be copied to the correct XML file or different XML needs to be loaded.

Comment: @cascaval: valid points. But the `kickstarter` is easy enough to get them created automatically.. :)

Comment: @konsolenfreddy thx for the idea.. theres only one small problem left. i think getLL only looking into the locallang.xml in the pi folder. as i created the tables with kickstarter the selectbox labels are in ../locallang_db.xml is there a way to read from that file? right now i copied some lines into my locallang.xml its ok but a bit dirty. if its not possible i will accept your answer in few days. thanks

Comment: @ggzone: They have the same structure, but unfortunately you can't load the `locallang_db.xml` explicitly in the frontend. A way around this is to create a symlink (if you're on a *nix) machine:  `rm typo3conf/ext/yourextension/pi1/locallang.xml; ln -s typo3conf/ext/yourextension/locallang_db.xml typo3conf/ext/yourextension/pi1/locallang.xml;`

Comment: hm yes i keep it with the copy/paste ... as the php code is clear and changes are not planed with categories its ok. i accept the answer now. very thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but when processing a submitted form with php there is no way to know the text shown against an option in a select box. Only the value is sent over. Either store it server-side before creating the form or use javascript to send it over with the form too. I'd need an example page or code to help with that part...

Comment: hm i thought theres maybe a typo3 function for that... nevermind i wait for some more viewer and next week if no success i just use the label also as value. tx anyway